# If $f(x)+g'(x)=g(x)+f'(x)$ is there any way to find what "$f(x)$" could be (without having $f'(x)$)?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Literally what the question asks. I just want to know the solution for $f(x)$. I don't just want to say:
$$f(x)=g(x)+f'(x)-g'(x)$$
I want to know if there is a way to have only one $f(x)$.

Comment: Well, $f(x)=g(x)=e^x$ certainly works! :)

Comment: @zz20s Well I mean f(x) in terms of g(x). :) But yes that does work.

Comment: Hint:  $\frac {d}{dx} e^{-x}f(x) = e^{-x}\left(f'(x)-f(x)\right)$.

Comment: @lulu so $f(x)= e^x*\int\frac{g'(x)-g(x)}{e^x}dx$??? $f(x)$ would have to equal $g(x)$ then...

Comment: Not quite.  See my posted solution below.

Comment: "Anyway" is a perfectly good word, but it does not mean the same thing as "any way". $\qquad$

Answer (score 10):

We have $$f'(x)-f(x)=g'(x)-g(x)\implies e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x))=e^{-x}(g'(x)-g(x))\implies$$$$\frac d{dx}\left[e^{-x}f(x)\right]=\frac d{dx}\left[e^{-x}g(x)\right]$$

We can now integrate to see $$ e^{-x}f(x) = e^{-x}g(x)+c\implies f(x)=g(x) +ce^x$$

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)+g'(x)=g(x)+f'(x)\quad\implies\quad f'(x)-g'(x)=f(x)-g(x)$

Let $f(x)-g(x)=h(x) \quad\implies\quad h'(x)=h(x) \quad\implies\quad h(x)=c\:e^x$

$h(x)=f(x)-g(x)=c\:e^x \quad\implies\quad f(x)=g(x)+c\:e^x$